Mouse wheel speed detection
In a WPF application, the MouseWheel events always report a delta of 120 per notch. However, if the wheel is moved very rapidly, some ticks are lost and not all moved notches are reported to the application.
This makes impossible to handle really fast movements. If the wheel is used for scrolling, what happens, paradoxically, is that scrolling is slower if the wheel is moved faster.
Does anyone know how to effectively get the real movement of the wheel without loss?
Does anyone know if there are special mouses that give the absolute position of the wheel or raise events with the real movement from the last call (so with variable delta in the event data)?

Does WPF provide the PreviewMouseWheel event? If so, tried it.

I think the normal thinking of mouse wheels is not to try and detect every scroll, but rather detect the first scroll then wait to determine if scrolling has stopped and then stop whatever event you are doing. Thats how mice with free scrollers work since you can spin them endlessly. You can see this for yourself. Scroll on a really large page, you will notice when you let off there is still one movement that will happen.

My mouse sometimes reports a delta of 240 or even 360, presumably when one or two MouseWheel events are skipped. Did you check that?

Also consider "high-precision" devices - those will report +/-40 instead of +/-120: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/w8cookbook/windows-precision-touchpad-devices - you may need to add <highResolutionScrollingAware to your app.manifest.

You may also want to test your code with a mousepad that emulates a mouse wheel by a vertical swipe gesture with two fingers. Mine reports integer values between 1 and somewhat around 400, depending on the speed of the gesture.

I was under the incorrect assumption that MouseWheelEventArgs.Delta would be 120/-120 regardless of the wheel movement speed. As a matter of fact, if the wheel is moved faster and more notches are displaced between two events, Delta is a multiple of 120.
